# What is preventing the Navigator from navigating to the Bottommenu screen and the SharePerence proivder from saving the data

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

What is preventing the Navigator from nagating to the Bottommenu screen and the SharePerence proivder from saving the data.

The Navigator is not navigating to the Bottommenu screen and the SharePerence proivder from saving the data.
I tried all removing the context too, but still.

The Navigation will only work if I bring above the SharedPreferenceHelper providers, but the SharedPreferenceHelper providers will not be save or trigered.

```
  loginUser() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();

      setState(() {
        _isloading = true;
      });

      try {
        SignInDataModel response = await AuthAPI().signIn(
            email: _emailController.text, password: _passwordController.text);

        if (response.flag != null && response.flag == true) {
          var userData = json.encode(response.user);
          var token = json.encode(response.token);
          if (context.mounted) {

            Provider.of<SharedPreferenceHelper>(context, listen: false)
                .setUserData(
              userData: userData,
            );
            Provider.of<SharedPreferenceHelper>(context, listen: false)
                .setUserToken(
              userToken: token,
            );
            Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const BottomBarMenu()),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          }

          _isloading = false;
        }

        showToast(msg: response.message ?? "An error occurred");
        setState(() {
          _isloading = false;
        });
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          _isloading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```